# Запросы идут раньше чем надо при использовании scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, android

Отправляю данные в БД MySQL каждые 20 секунд посредством `scheduleAtFixedRate`.
 Первый запрос происходит по времени ровно через 20 секунд, но затем начинается "каша": запрос повторяется когда захочет, а не по интервалу в  20 секунд.
Смотрю в логах - идет отправка чуть ли не каждую секунду, а порой за одну секунду чуть ли не по 3 раза.

```
task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        now = new Date();
        times = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(now);
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"moe tekuweee vrema" + times);
        Sender s = new Sender(getApplicationContext(), number, urlAddress,
                mlatitude, mlogtud, id, status);
        s.execute();
    }
};
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 20000);
```

Comment: Хм. Учитывая, что второй аргумент `scheduleAtFixedRate` установлен в 0, то странно почему у вас первый запрос происходит через 20 секунд,  если должен выполниться сразу без пауз. Вы уверены, что именно первый, а не второй запрос происходит через 20 секунд?

Comment: Тоесть все дело во 2м аргументе ?

Comment: не совсем. второй аргумент указывает через какое время будет запущен первый таск. Третий аргумент указывает время ожидания между успешными завершениями тасков. Учитывая что первый таск у вас начинается с ожидания, то я бы проверил а действительно ли у вас в коде так, как вы указали в примере? Может вы все же передаете 20000 во второй аргумент, а в третий 0? Тогда программа должна вести себя как вы описали в вопросе.

Comment: вы правыыыыы.!!!!

Comment: Но веравно это помогает лишь на 1 минуту затем сново получается каша

Comment: @GreyGoblin после 2 отпрправок сноово все обваливется и он посылает ежесекундно .

Comment: время паузы у вас жестко задано, как в примере или хранится в переменной? Если в переменной, то добавьте её в лог, возможно где то в процессе выполнения меняется её значение?

Comment: все как впримере .Может ли быть это утечкой памяти ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android не является системой *Real Time*, то есть точность исполнения не поддерживается на уровне оси. В данном случае, если внимательно прочитать синопсис метода `scheduleAtFixedRate()`, то вы прочтете:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

По русски говоря не гарантируется точность выполнения через заданные интервалы, более-менее гарантируется их периодичность на длинном промежутке.

Я бы вам посоветовал вычислять время через `System.currentTimeMillis()` и в зависимости от этого отправлять запросы, если прошло *нужное* время.

Comment: Значит это не моя ошибка .а можно ли найти какието альтернативы scheduleAtFixedRate() но более точные

Comment: Запускайте `Runnable`, который скажем раз в 5 секунд циклится и проверяет когда был последний запрос, если запрос был более 20 секунд назад - инициируется запрос. Чем чаще будете проверять тем, точнее будет.

Comment: а может ли быть это утечкой памяти ???